# Socket Programming java using datagram multiple packets

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I am trying to make a client-server program. Where in client i am getting multiple inputs from user and i have to pass it to server. Server uses that info and does some calculation and sends back the result.
important parts from Client code:

```
private byte[] buf = new byte[256];
private byte[] buf2 = new byte[256];
private byte[] buf3 = new byte[256];
while (true) {

Arrays.fill(buf, (byte) 0); 

buf = jTextField1.getText().trim().getBytes();
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 8000);
socket.send(sendPacket);

buf2 = jTextField2.getText().trim().getBytes();
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf2, buf2.length, address, 8000);
socket.send(sendPacket);

buf3 = jTextField3.getText().trim().getBytes();
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf3, buf3.length, address, 8000);
socket.send(sendPacket);

//Get result from Server
socket.receive(recivePacket);
double result  = Double.parseDouble(new String(buf).trim());
System.out.println("Result" +result);
```

}

On Server side I am trying to recieve the data(which is not working)

```
   byte[] buf = new byte[256];
   DatagramPacket  recivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
   DatagramPacket dgp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    while (true) {
            Arrays.fill(buf, (byte) 0);
            serverSocket.receive(recivePacket);

            System.out.println("host Name is " + 
   recivePacket.getAddress().getHostName() + '\n');

            while (true) {
                serverSocket.receive(dgp);
                System.out.println("String=====" + new String(buf));
            }
```

Please help me out here. What is wrong with this code ... I am completely stuck 
So, its strange that sometimes it works. But it gives me value from last buffer. Other values are lost.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just dont use datagrams for that.

Take a look into the standard TCP protocol. Makes more sense for you.

This should be done via ServerSockets. (very easy to use)

Comment: It is mandatory to use datagram. Thats the part of assignment.

Comment: okay let me take a look. Have you done debugging?

Comment: please see my answer.

Comment: Don't attach the same `buf` to two different `DatagramPacket` instances.

Comment: what do u mean @rustyx . U mean on client code or server?

Comment: on both sides. Always create a new byte[]. Just look at my answer.

Comment: What you can do is using the same instance but always create a new byte[] with: new byte[...]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think each time you recieve something on the server, you need to create a new DatagramPacket/byte[] for that.
What I do is creating e a new DatagramPacket each time I recieve something like this:

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[max_data_size], max_data_size);
socket.receive(packet);
```

My `max_data_size is normally around 1024 bits`.

Then you could read stuff like client, port, length etc:

```
InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
int port = packet.getPort();
int len = packet.getLength();
byte[] data = packet.getData();
```

And usually, you should then be able to simply send a new datagramPacket back to the given InetAddress/port.

You want multiple inputs from the user?
Pack everything in only one package.

---

```
private YourClass newInstance(byte[] bytes){
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInput in = null;
    YourClass o = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        o = (YourClass)in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        }
    }
    return o;
}

private byte[] toBytes(YourClass object){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        object.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        out.writeObject(object);
        out.flush();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: So here is what i tried in server:                                                                          
        while (true) {
  byte[] buf = new byte[256];
  DatagramPacket dgp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  serverSocket.receive(dgp);
    
  InetAddress address = dgp.getAddress();
  int port = dgp.getPort();
  int len = dgp.getLength();
  byte[] data = dgp.getData();
  System.out.println("String=====" + new String(data));
  }
But no change. I get only one result.

Comment: I was also thinking about sending some serialized object but I have no clue how to deserialised it on server side

Comment: there you go. This is what I use. Just make sure that YourClass implements Serializable.

Comment: Yes atlast it worked with Serialized object. Thank u so much @Finn for your help.. Thanks!!